# nusmv 2.6 build failed

Tags: cmake, model-checking

I downloaded the nusmv-2.6.0.tar.gz and followed the readme file in nusmv-2.6.0/nusmv/README.TXT to build it but there were some problems. I guess there may be a wrong config somewhere, but I didn't find it.

```
tar -jxvf nusmv-2.6.0.tar.gz
cd nusmv-2.6.0/nusmv
mkdir build
cmake ..
```

error information

```
~/workspace/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV/build$ cmake ..
writing CuDD config file
writing MiniSat config file
linking with realine libraries: _readline_lib-NOTFOUND;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtermcap.so
writing NuSMV config file
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
_readline_lib
    linked by target "NUSMV_ADDONSCORE_LIB" in directory /home/ww/workspace/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV
    linked by target "NUSMV_CORE_LIB" in directory /home/ww/workspace/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV
    linked by target "NUSMV_GRAMMAR_LIB" in directory /home/ww/workspace/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV
    linked by target "NUSMV_RBC_LIB" in directory /home/ww/workspace/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV
    linked by target "NUSMV_SHELL_LIB" in directory /home/ww/workspace/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ww/workspace/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ww/workspace/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I have installed readline-common already ,and this is the new output,

```
writing CuDD config file
Downloading MiniSat from https://github.com/niklasso/minisat/archive/37dc6c67e2af26379d88ce349eb9c4c6160e8543.zip --> /home/ww/workspace/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV/build/build-MiniSat/37dc6c67e2af26379d88ce349eb9c4c6160e8543.zip
writing MiniSat config file
linking with realine libraries: _readline_lib-NOTFOUND;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtermcap.so
writing NuSMV config file
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
_readline_lib
    linked by target "NUSMV_ADDONSCORE_LIB" in directory /home/ww/workspace/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV
    linked by target "NUSMV_CORE_LIB" in directory /home/ww/workspace/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV
    linked by target "NUSMV_GRAMMAR_LIB" in directory /home/ww/workspace/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV
    linked by target "NUSMV_RBC_LIB" in directory /home/ww/workspace/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV
    linked by target "NUSMV_SHELL_LIB" in directory /home/ww/workspace/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV

te]
-- [download 6% complete]
-- [download 8% complete]
-- [download 10% complete]
-- [download 12% complete]
-- [download 13% complete]
-- [download 15% complete]
-- [download 17% complete]
-- [download 19% complete]
-- [download 20% complete]
-- [download 22% complete]
-- [download 24% complete]
-- [download 26% complete]
-- [download 27% complete]
-- [download 29% complete]
-- [download 31% complete]
-- [download 33% complete]
-- [download 34% complete]
-- [download 36% complete]
-- [download 38% complete]
-- [download 40% complete]
-- [download 42% complete]
-- [download 43% complete]
-- [download 45% complete]
-- [download 47% complete]
-- [download 49% complete]
-- [download 50% complete]
-- [download 52% complete]
-- [download 54% complete]
-- [download 56% complete]
-- [download 57% complete]
-- [download 59% complete]
-- [download 61% complete]
-- [download 63% complete]
-- [download 64% complete]
-- [download 66% complete]
-- [download 68% complete]
-- [download 70% complete]
-- [download 72% complete]
-- [download 73% complete]
-- [download 75% complete]
-- [download 77% complete]
-- [download 79% complete]
-- [download 80% complete]
-- [download 82% complete]
-- [download 84% complete]
-- [download 85% complete]
-- [download 87% complete]
-- [download 89% complete]
-- [download 91% complete]
-- [download 92% complete]
-- [download 94% complete]
-- [download 96% complete]
-- [download 98% complete]
-- [download 99% complete]
-- [download 100% complete]
-- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so (found version "2.9.1") 
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.26") 
-- found xml2 library xml2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so
-- Performing Test _have_funcattr_noreturn
-- Performing Test _have_funcattr_noreturn - Success
-- Performing Test _have_funcattr_warn_unused_result
-- Performing Test _have_funcattr_warn_unused_result - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_MALLOC
-- Performing Test HAVE_MALLOC - Success
-- Looking for malloc.h
-- Looking for malloc.h - found
-- Looking for dirent.h
-- Looking for dirent.h - found
-- Looking for dlfcn.h
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - found
-- Looking for errno.h
-- Looking for errno.h - found
-- Looking for float.h
-- Looking for float.h - found
-- Looking for fnmatch.h
-- Looking for fnmatch.h - found
-- Looking for inttypes.h
-- Looking for inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for limits.h
-- Looking for limits.h - found
-- Looking for memory.h
-- Looking for memory.h - found
-- Looking for ndir.h
-- Looking for ndir.h - not found
-- Looking for regex.h
-- Looking for regex.h - found
-- Looking for signal.h
-- Looking for signal.h - found
-- Looking for stdbool.h
-- Looking for stdbool.h - found
-- Looking for stdlib.h
-- Looking for stdlib.h - found
-- Looking for string.h
-- Looking for string.h - found
-- Looking for strings.h
-- Looking for strings.h - found
-- Looking for sys/dir.h
-- Looking for sys/dir.h - found
-- Looking for sys/ndir.h
-- Looking for sys/ndir.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h - found
-- Looking for sys/param.h
-- Looking for sys/param.h - found
-- Looking for sys/resource.h
-- Looking for sys/resource.h - found
-- Looking for sys/signal.h
-- Looking for sys/signal.h - found
-- Looking for sys/stat.h
-- Looking for sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for sys/time.h
-- Looking for sys/time.h - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Looking for floor
-- Looking for floor - not found
-- Looking for getenv
-- Looking for getenv - found
-- Looking for getpid
-- Looking for getpid - found
-- Looking for isatty
-- Looking for isatty - found
-- Looking for memmove
-- Looking for memmove - found
-- Looking for memset
-- Looking for memset - found
-- Looking for mkstemp
-- Looking for mkstemp - found
-- Looking for mktemp
-- Looking for mktemp - found
-- Looking for popen
-- Looking for popen - found
-- Looking for pow
-- Looking for pow - not found
-- Looking for random
-- Looking for random - found
-- Looking for realloc
-- Looking for realloc - found
-- Looking for setvbuf
-- Looking for setvbuf - found
-- Looking for srandom
-- Looking for srandom - found
-- Looking for strcasecmp
-- Looking for strcasecmp - found
-- Looking for strchr
-- Looking for strchr - found
-- Looking for strrchr
-- Looking for strrchr - found
-- Looking for strstr
-- Looking for strstr - found
-- Looking for strtod
-- Looking for strtod - found
-- Looking for strtol
-- Looking for strtol - found
-- Looking for strtoull
-- Looking for strtoull - found
-- Looking for system
-- Looking for system - found
-- Looking for tmpnam
-- Looking for tmpnam - found
-- Looking for vprintf
-- Looking for vprintf - found
-- Performing Test HAVE__BOOL
-- Performing Test HAVE__BOOL - Success
-- Check size of int
-- Check size of int - done
-- Check size of long
-- Check size of long - done
-- Check size of long long
-- Check size of long long - done
-- Check size of void *
-- Check size of void * - done
-- Found Doxygen: /usr/bin/doxygen (found version "1.8.6") 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ww/workspace/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ww/workspace/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

`

Comment: CMake could not find your read line lib. To get more inforamations, you can re-run cmake after deleting the content your build directory. Please share that output, at least the part concerning readline detection. Have you the library installed? If you have and CMake still fails to find readline, you should add the path to it to the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.

Comment: I have installed readline-common already ,and this is the new output,

Comment: Readline is still not found. As I told you, you could add it's path to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have reinstall readline lib again, this time I installed libreadline and libreadline-dev and there is no probliem now.

Answer (score 0):

CMake could not find your read line lib. To get more information, you can re-run CMake after deleting the content your build directory.

Make sure to have the readline library and its headers (readline-dev) installed. Maybe you have to add the install path to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.